# Why doesn't this objects variable expression work?

Tags: javascript

Can someone please explain why hotel.availableRooms is NaN? I am trying to learn objects in JavaScript. Thanks!

```js
var hotel = {
  name: 'The Shining',
  totalRooms: 238,
  bookedRooms: 0,
  availableRooms: this.totalRooms - this.bookedRooms,
  roomTypes: ['single', 'double', 'haunted'],
  bookRoom: function() {
    this.availableRooms -= 1;
    this.bookedRooms += 1;
  }
};


hotel.bookRoom();

console.log(hotel.totalRooms);
console.log(hotel.bookedRooms);
console.log(hotel.availableRooms);
```

Comment: availableRooms has to be a function

Comment: @mtizziani I did try to make this a function. It didn't seem to work the few ways that I tried it, could you provide me an example of how availableRooms should look, if I were to write my code as it is?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When the expression `availableRooms: this.totalRooms - this.bookedRooms,` is evaluated `this` is not `hotel` but whatever context you are running your code.

```
var hotel = {
  name: 'The Shining',
  totalRooms: 238,
  bookedRooms: 0,
  roomTypes: ['single', 'double', 'haunted'],
  bookRoom: function() {
    this.availableRooms -= 1;
    this.bookedRooms += 1;
  }
}

hotel.availableRooms = hotel.totalRooms - hotel.bookedRooms
```

Or

```
  Object.defineProperty(hotel, 'availableRooms', {
      get: function() {
         return this.totalRooms - this.bookedRooms
      }
  })
```

Comment: I'm a little lost then. When I take "this." off of the variables the code doesn't run. I am trying to calculate the available rooms, should I be doing this as an anonymous function or is there some other way of doing that. Thanks for the response by the way.

Comment: Sorry I see you added more, while I was writing my comment. so it sounds like best practice is not to use an expression in the object but to query the object to get the information you need, is that right?

Comment: It depends on your requirements. You could either statically initialize value after object creation or you could make `availableRooms` to be computed property as in my second example. Then you wont need to manually decrement its value inside `bookRoom` method. Getter will be called every time you access `hotel.availableRooms`.

Comment: @TYPKRFT he didn't say 'its best practices', he just said your understanding of the code was incorrect. This is a common Javascript mistake. Many people assume that the this keyword in Javascript works like they might expect it to in Java, C++, or PHP. Since there are no "classes", only higher order functions, the `this` variable references the current objects context. Depending on where the code is placed, that may be `window`, or `document`, or something else entirely. You need to create a function because you need a new context. You were trying to treat prototypical object creation like OOP

Comment: Yep. `this` in javascript is confusing for programmers coming say from java. Because it is function call context which is dynamic and might be not what you think it is.